# Whats the best way to access to Photoshop Smart Objects?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I need to have an access to Photoshop Smart Objects?

- Scripting,
- CS SDK,
- etc?

Comment: I consider any programming languages, but C# is preferrable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "access." Do you need to display them in an application, while keeping them editable in photoshop?  Is this a web application?  Try FlashCatalyst.  That gives the best integration into Adobe Illustrator and Photoshop files while still allowing you to manipulate the objects via ActionScript/Flex.

At times, Catalyst can be fairly rudimentary. For more powerful control maybe, importing the graphics into the Flash Professional CS5 IDE is what you need.  You lose the ability to edit in Photoshop but the IDE has extensive editing capabilities of its own.  From there, you can create MovieClips out of each of your graphics, export the file as a SWC, and manipulate those graphics via Flex.

Generally speaking, if you're going to be working with Adobe tools such as Photoshop/Illustrator, you're going to have an easier time programmatically manipulating the products of those tools by using other Adobe tools such as Flash/Flex/Catalyst.

If these approaches aren't suitable, elaborate on what you need to do, exactly and maybe other StackOverflow members can be of more assistance.

Hope that helps in some way.

Comment: Could you, by any way, access the bitmap data (Read and Write) of Photoshop Layer using Flash?